# ComboBox options based on another ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

below is the code I'm working on to make a UserForm. I'm new to using UserForm and am tryin to populate ComboBox 2 with ComboBox 1 selection. ComboBox 1 holds the name of the worksheets and I'd like ComboBox 2 to update with the column heading names of the selected worksheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private m_Cancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get Cancelled() As Variant
    Cancelled = m_Cancelled
End Property

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    'Initialize ComboBox2
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ComboBox2.Clear
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    Debug.Print "Here"; ComboBox1.Value
'    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
'        Case ComboBox1.Value
    With Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value)
        Debug.Print "Active Worksheet";
        Dim InitialArray() As Variant
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim ColCount As Integer
        '    Debug.Print ColCount; RowStart
        Do While IsEmpty(Cells(1, ColCount + 1).Value) = False
            ColCount = ColCount + 1
    '        Debug.Print Cells(RowStart, ColCount)
        Loop
        Debug.Print ColCount; "Cols"
    End With
'    End Select
    
'    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
        For i = 1 To ColCount
            Cells(1, i).Add
        Next i
'    End Select
    
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    ' Hide the Userform and set cancelled to true
    Hide
    m_Cancelled = True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    ComboBox1.Clear
    
    'Initialize ComboBox1
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wCount As Long: wCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
    Dim wsNames() As String: ReDim wsNames(1 To wCount)

    Dim ws As Worksheet, w As Long

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            w = w + 1
            wsNames(w) = ws.Name
        End If
    Next ws

    If w < wCount Then ReDim Preserve wsNames(1 To w)

    ComboBox1.List = wsNames
    
    
    

    
    
'    ReDim InitialArray(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count) As Variant
'    Dim i As Integer
'
'    ComboBox1.Clear
'    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
'        InitialArray(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
'    Next i
'    ComboBox1.List = InitialArray
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer _
                                        , CloseMode As Integer)
    
    ' Prevent the form being unloaded
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then Cancel = True
    
    ' Hide the Userform and set cancelled to true
    Hide
    m_Cancelled = True
    
End Sub

Function GetComboBox1() As String
    GetComboBox1 = ComboBox1.Value
End Function
```

Comment: in your ComboBox1_Change script, you'll want to confirm that the user has made a valid selection before continuing. With comboboxes, the user can type in any string, which will give you an error when you try `Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value)`. You also should force the conversion to String, in case the user types a number. e.g. `Worksheets(1)` will look at index 1, instead of name "1". Forcing the conversion `Worksheets(CStr(ComboBox1.Value))` will make sure its always looking for a name, not an index.

Comment: For quickly filling a ComboBox list with the column headers, you can just do `ComboBox2.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A1:X1").Value)`. You can make that into a dynamic range by quickly calculating the last column, like `LastColumn = WS.Rows(1).Columns(WS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` where `WS` is your worksheet object. Then your range could be `WS.Range("A1").Resize(1,LastColumn)`

Comment: Why your code might not be working: You have `With Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value)` but you forgot the leading `.` on `IsEmpty(Cells(1, ColCount + 1).Value)`. Your `Cells` is not using the With Object and is defaulting to `ActiveSheet`. Same with `Cells(1, i).Add`. But that line is not correct anyway, I think you meant `ComboBox2.AddItem .Cells(1, i).Value`

Comment: ```ComboBox2.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A1:X1").Value)```

I attempted to use this but it only took from the activeworksheet and not the worksheet i chose in combobox1 @Toddleson

Comment: Yeah, you need to use the With Object, or add the worksheet object like `ComboBox2.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Range("A1:X1").Value)` or `ComboBox2.List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets(CStr(ComboBox1.Value)).Range("A1:X1").Value)`

Comment: maybe try something like this (minimal code, just for two combobox) : `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` ... `For Each sh In Worksheets` ... `If sh.Visible = True Then ComboBox1.AddItem sh.Name` ... `Next` .. `End Sub` ---> This sub is to populate ComboBox1 with each visible sheet name.  ... `Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()` ... `Set hdr = Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlConstants)` ... `ComboBox2.List = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(hdr))` ... `End Sub` ---> this sub is to populate ComboBox2 with each header name of the selected sheet in ComboBox1.